# Unable to Install ffmpeg in Databricks Environment

Tags: ffmpeg

I used to install `ffmpeg` without any problem by running `sudo apt-get -y install ffmpeg` as a shell command in Databricks.

Suddenly, I've been getting a 404 error in some of the links as you can see in this image:

[image: picture of a screen showing a partial terminal window]

However, it runs successfully sometimes. From what I've observed, when there are more than 10 hit links on typing `sudo apt-get update`, `ffmpeg` gets installed successfully. But it usually returns 5 links as shown in this image:

[image: another picture of a screen showing a partial terminal window]

I've tried `dist-upgrade`, `fix-missing`, and `apt-get clean`.

Kindly help me in resolving this as it's been a pain to get around this problem and I don't understand how to use Ubuntu very well.

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists...
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   libcap2-bin libpam-cap zulu-8 zulu-repo
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
   zulu8 zulu8-ca zulu8-ca-doc zulu8-ca-jdk zulu8-ca-jdk-headless zulu8-ca-jre
   zulu8-ca-jre-headless zulu8-doc zulu8-jdk zulu8-jdk-headless zulu8-jre
   zulu8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt-get -y install ffmpeg`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9 libasyncns0
  libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libcaca0
  libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.9
  libdc1394-22 libflac8 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libiec61883-0 libigdgmm11
  libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmysofa1 libnorm1
  libnuma1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0 libpgm-5.2-0
  libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2 libsamplerate0
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsndfile1 libsndio7.0
  libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3
  libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2
  libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbisenc2 libvpx6 libwavpack1 libx264-155
  libx265-179 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc i965-va-driver-shaders libbluray-bdj jackd2 libportaudio2
  opus-tools pulseaudio libraw1394-doc serdi sndiod sordi speex opencl-icd
  libvdpau-va-gl1 nvidia-vdpau-driver nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver
  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9
  libasyncns0 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7
  libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libcaca0 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1
  libcodec2-0.9 libdc1394-22 libflac8 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libiec61883-0
  libigdgmm11 libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmysofa1
  libnorm1 libnuma1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0
  libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2
  libsamplerate0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsndfile1
  libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2
  libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbisenc2 libvpx6 libwavpack1
  libx264-155 libx265-179 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all
  vdpau-driver-all
0 upgraded, 82 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 221 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libslang2 amd64 2.3.2-4 [429 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libnuma1 amd64 2.0.12-1 [20.8 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libusb-1.0-0 amd64 2:1.0.23-2build1 [46.5 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libaom0 amd64 1.0.0.errata1-3build1 [1,160 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libva2 amd64 2.7.0-2 [53.5 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libva-drm2 amd64 2.7.0-2 [7,044 B]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libva-x11-2 amd64 2.7.0-2 [11.9 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libvdpau1 amd64 1.3-1ubuntu2 [25.6 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 ocl-icd-libopencl1 amd64 2.2.11-1ubuntu1 [30.3 kB]
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavutil56 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libcodec2-0.9 amd64 0.9.2-2 [7,886 kB]
Err:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavutil56 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgsm1 amd64 1.0.18-2 [24.4 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmp3lame0 amd64 3.100-3 [133 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libopus0 amd64 1.3.1-0ubuntu1 [191 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libshine3 amd64 3.1.1-2 [23.2 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libspeex1 amd64 1.2~rc1.2-1.1ubuntu1.20.04.1 [53.2 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsoxr0 amd64 0.1.3-2build1 [78.0 kB]
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswresample3 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libtheora0 amd64 1.1.1+dfsg.1-15ubuntu2 [162 kB]
Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswresample3 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libtwolame0 amd64 0.4.0-2 [47.6 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libvorbisenc2 amd64 1.3.6-2ubuntu1 [70.7 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libvpx6 amd64 1.8.2-1build1 [820 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libwavpack1 amd64 5.2.0-1ubuntu0.1 [77.3 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libx264-155 amd64 2:0.155.2917+git0a84d98-2 [521 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libx265-179 amd64 3.2.1-1build1 [1,060 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libxvidcore4 amd64 2:1.3.7-1 [201 kB]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libzvbi-common all 0.2.35-17 [32.5 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libzvbi0 amd64 0.2.35-17 [237 kB]
Ign:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libraw1394-11 amd64 2.1.2-1 [30.7 kB]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libavc1394-0 amd64 0.5.4-5 [16.2 kB]
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libass9 amd64 1:0.14.0-2 [88.0 kB]
Err:29 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavcodec58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libbluray2 amd64 1:1.2.0-1 [138 kB]
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libchromaprint1 amd64 1.4.3-3build1 [37.6 kB]
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libgme0 amd64 0.6.2-1build1 [123 kB]
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libmpg123-0 amd64 1.25.13-1 [124 kB]
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libopenmpt0 amd64 0.4.11-1build1 [599 kB]
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libssh-gcrypt-4 amd64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2 [202 kB]
Ign:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavformat58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libbs2b0 amd64 3.1.0+dfsg-2.2build1 [10.2 kB]
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libflite1 amd64 2.1-release-3 [12.8 MB]
Err:39 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavformat58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libserd-0-0 amd64 0.30.2-1 [46.6 kB]
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsord-0-0 amd64 0.16.4-1 [19.5 kB]
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsratom-0-0 amd64 0.6.4-1 [16.9 kB]
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 liblilv-0-0 amd64 0.24.6-1ubuntu0.1 [40.6 kB]
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libmysofa1 amd64 1.0~dfsg0-1 [39.2 kB]
Ign:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpostproc55 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libsamplerate0 amd64 0.1.9-2 [939 kB]
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 librubberband2 amd64 1.8.2-1build1 [89.4 kB]
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswscale5 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libvidstab1.1 amd64 1.1.0-2 [35.0 kB]
Err:47 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libpostproc55 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libnorm1 amd64 1.5.8+dfsg2-2build1 [290 kB]
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libpgm-5.2-0 amd64 5.2.122~dfsg-3ubuntu1 [158 kB]
Err:50 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libswscale5 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libzmq5 amd64 4.3.2-2ubuntu1 [242 kB]
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavfilter7 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libcaca0 amd64 0.99.beta19-2.1ubuntu1.20.04.2 [203 kB]
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libcdio18 amd64 2.0.0-2 [58.6 kB]
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libcdio-cdda2 amd64 10.2+2.0.0-1 [17.6 kB]
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libcdio-paranoia2 amd64 10.2+2.0.0-1 [16.2 kB]
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libdc1394-22 amd64 2.2.5-2.1 [79.6 kB]
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libiec61883-0 amd64 1.2.0-3 [24.3 kB]
Err:55 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavfilter7 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:62 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libjack-jackd2-0 amd64 1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 [267 kB]
Get:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libopenal-data all 1:1.19.1-1 [162 kB]
Get:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsndio7.0 amd64 1.5.0-3 [24.5 kB]
Get:65 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libopenal1 amd64 1:1.19.1-1 [492 kB]
Get:66 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libasyncns0 amd64 0.8-6 [12.1 kB]
Get:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 libflac8 amd64 1.3.3-1build1 [103 kB]
Get:68 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.28-7ubuntu0.1 [170 kB]
Get:69 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libpulse0 amd64 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.13 [262 kB]
Get:70 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.10+dfsg1-3 [407 kB]
Ign:71 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavdevice58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:72 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Ign:73 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
Get:74 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libigdgmm11 amd64 20.1.1+ds1-1 [111 kB]
Get:75 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 intel-media-va-driver amd64 20.1.1+dfsg1-1 [1,764 kB]
Err:71 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavdevice58 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:76 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libaacs0 amd64 0.9.0-2 [50.1 kB]
Get:77 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libbdplus0 amd64 0.1.2-3 [47.3 kB]
Get:78 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 mesa-va-drivers amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 [2,970 kB]
Err:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 libavresample4 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:73 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 ffmpeg amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Get:79 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 mesa-vdpau-drivers amd64 21.2.6-0ubuntu0.1~20.04.2 [3,089 kB]
Get:80 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 i965-va-driver amd64 2.4.0-0ubuntu1 [924 kB]
Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 va-driver-all amd64 2.7.0-2 [4,020 B]
Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 vdpau-driver-all amd64 1.3-1ubuntu2 [4,596 B]
Fetched 40.8 MB in 11s (3,784 kB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavutil56_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswresample3_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavcodec58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavformat58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libpostproc55_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libswscale5_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavfilter7_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice58_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/libavresample4_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/ffmpeg/ffmpeg_4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9 libasyncns0
  libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7 libavformat58
  libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0 libcaca0
  libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1 libcodec2-0.9
  libdc1394-22 libflac8 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libiec61883-0 libigdgmm11
  libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmysofa1 libnorm1
  libnuma1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0 libpgm-5.2-0
  libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2 libsamplerate0
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsndfile1 libsndio7.0
  libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4 libswresample3
  libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2 libva-x11-2
  libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbisenc2 libvpx6 libwavpack1 libx264-155
  libx265-179 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0 mesa-va-drivers
  mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all vdpau-driver-all
Suggested packages:
  ffmpeg-doc i965-va-driver-shaders libbluray-bdj jackd2 libportaudio2
  opus-tools pulseaudio libraw1394-doc serdi sndiod sordi speex opencl-icd
  libvdpau-va-gl1 nvidia-vdpau-driver nvidia-legacy-340xx-vdpau-driver
  nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ffmpeg i965-va-driver intel-media-va-driver libaacs0 libaom0 libass9
  libasyncns0 libavc1394-0 libavcodec58 libavdevice58 libavfilter7
  libavformat58 libavresample4 libavutil56 libbdplus0 libbluray2 libbs2b0
  libcaca0 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcdio18 libchromaprint1
  libcodec2-0.9 libdc1394-22 libflac8 libflite1 libgme0 libgsm1 libiec61883-0
  libigdgmm11 libjack-jackd2-0 liblilv-0-0 libmp3lame0 libmpg123-0 libmysofa1
  libnorm1 libnuma1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenmpt0 libopus0
  libpgm-5.2-0 libpostproc55 libpulse0 libraw1394-11 librubberband2
  libsamplerate0 libsdl2-2.0-0 libserd-0-0 libshine3 libslang2 libsndfile1
  libsndio7.0 libsord-0-0 libsoxr0 libspeex1 libsratom-0-0 libssh-gcrypt-4
  libswresample3 libswscale5 libtheora0 libtwolame0 libusb-1.0-0 libva-drm2
  libva-x11-2 libva2 libvdpau1 libvidstab1.1 libvorbisenc2 libvpx6 libwavpack1
  libx264-155 libx265-179 libxvidcore4 libzmq5 libzvbi-common libzvbi0
  mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers ocl-icd-libopencl1 va-driver-all
  vdpau-driver-all
0 upgraded, 82 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
Need to get 49.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 221 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

This command (without -y) keeps running after the above output is shown. There is no prompt in Databricks asking to proceed or anything.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1417508/edit) and include the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`.  If you are using other commands, include the output of each of those too. *Please do not upload images of text.*  Images of text are hard to read and they are also impossible for us to work with. Instead, copy/paste the entire output and put [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) on the line before and the line after each paste.

Comment: FYI, when you use the `-y` flag, you are telling `apt` not to bother you with confirmation prompts or other notifications that may alert you to a problem . Don't use this flag unless you're confident that you know exactly what you're doing and that there won't be any issues. Definitely do not continue to use this flag on subsequent attempts when there has been a problem. I see nothing wrong or unusual with the second command except that I don't know what is the first repo. Also you're supposed to always run the apt update command, and make sure it's clean before you do anything else in apt.

Comment: @Nmath Hi. Thank you for responding. I have added the outputs of the commands you requested. The output of `sudo apt-get -y install ffmpeg` is huge, hence I did not include it.
However, the errors I am getting are in the format "Err{number}: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 {lib_ _ _ _ } amd64 amd64 7:4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]"

Comment: These details are a bit ambiguous. Don't worry about the length of the output. Include the full output of each command. That's actually even more important if they are "huge". Don't use the -y flag either. Finally, do not manipulate anything inside the paste. Inside the pasted output, do not add or remove characters, line breaks, annotations, or spaces. Just add code fences on the line before and the line after each paste. Look at the edit history for examples. So the info is complete and unambiguous, please do not deviate from these instructions. Comment @nmath when you're done.

Comment: One thing that could be wrong is that your packages are not already up-to-date. It's best to make sure that packages are up-to-date before attempting to add anything new. If your system is not up-to-date and you try to add new software, you can break things and cause dependency problems.

Comment: @Nmath I have added the enitre outputs of `sudo apt-get -y install ffmpeg` and `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`. Please have a look.

Comment: Your package management is definitely a mess.  Is that the complete output of `sudo apt update`? What is the purpose of the repo `https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb`? I don't think this is a compatible repo for your system. If that's true that can cause widespread issues and break your package manager. Also, what is going on with the `zulu8` packages? Are those still not updated when you run `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: I don't know what is this repo `https://repos.azul.com/zulu/deb` and `zulu8` packages. And yes, those are the complete output of `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Please let me know how to fix it. I have no idea. I just need to install ffmpeg on that system. That's all I have to deal with ubuntu, and I don't know how to. @Nmath

Comment: That source isn't included with Ubuntu so it would have been added manually at some point. All of the packages held back seem related to that source. So if you don't need it anymore, you can remove it. Then run `sudo apt update` again to update the sources and `sudo apt upgrade` until all of your existing packages are up-to-date. You may also be prompted to run `sudo apt autoremove` which will remove dependent packages no longer being used. Just make sure it won't remove anything you need.

Comment: Once your system is finally up-to-date and your package manager is not throwing errors, you should be able to install ffmpeg especially if you're only using the default sources.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your Databricks runtime release is outdated. I got the exact same error using a 12.2 ML LTS runtime.

Some time after LTS support has stopped,  Ubuntu moves the `archive...` and `security...` URL with the repository of the relevant library to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

On a **standard Ubuntu**, you can try using

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

to enable the repository URLs are also updated with these `old-releases...`. Check [here](https://operavps.com/docs/404-not-found-error-on-ubuntu/) for some possibly necessary additional steps.

On **Databricks** the problem was gone, by simple choosing a runtime, with an Ubuntu LTS version, which hasn't support stopped yet (in my case 13.1 ML LTS)